# How to signal child component when wrapper state has changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There's a wrapper pure component, that renders a child component.

The wrapper implements a file-upload functionality to the backend, independently of the child component (promise).

How do I trigger a re-render of the child component when the promise in the wrapper resolves?

```
// this wrapper renders a toolbar and beneath it the children
const Wrapper = ({children}) => {
  const onChange = (event) => {
    // this simulates the upload promise resolving 
    console.log("change!")
    // Q: how do I signal children that this happened?
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <AppBar>
        <Button onChange={onChange}>Click</Button>
      </AppBar>
      {children}
      <Footer/>
    </>
}
```

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

  return (
    // render some data
  )

}
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ChildComponent />
    </Wrapper>   
  )
}
```

Comment: Just to understand, you want to toggle the child component's display based on the upload being triggered?
Like if upload off - show child
Uploading - hide child
Upload done - show child

Comment: @jaybhatt if the file was uploaded successfully I need the child to refresh: the child might need to fetch new content from the backend. My problem is getting that signal from the wrapper to the child.

Comment: There are two possible solutions that I would go towards. One is to use `hooks` instead of the `Wrapper` component. In case you still want to go with `Wrapper` component, you can use render props pattern. Link to [React JS Render Props docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render)

Comment: I think I need the Wrapper because it also takes care of layout, etc.
how would a hook approach work?

Comment: I think wrapper will have some context where it will push data whenever it uploads and the same can be extracted out using the hooks, like both can go in sync.